# Is it more efficient to union from sub-query or combine two outer queries?

Tags: performance, db2, subquery, query-performance

I searched for this but couldn't find the response I needed.  So my apologies if this has already been asked.

I'm asking in regards to `DB2` but I suppose this would apply, generally speaking, to just about any database.

Anyway, say I have two tables in the same database:

```
select ID, EMAIL from TBL1
select ID, EMAIL from TBL2
```

What I then want to do is search for a field within those two tables.  The field could be in either table.

So, I have tried the following:

```
select ID, EMAIL from TBL1 where EMAIL = 'blah@aol.com'
union
select ID, EMAIL from TBL2 where EMAIL = 'blah@aol.com'
```

This works.  But is redundant and ugly.

However, is it more efficient than:

```
select T.* from
(
    select ID, EMAIL from TBL1
    union
    select ID, EMAIL from TBL2
) T where T.EMAIL = 'blah@aol.com'
```

Both seem to work.  Unfortunately, I don't have any real profiling tools for DB2 (along with restricted access) so I can't seem to figure out which is better.  They both execute at roughly the same speed in the console but that isn't a good indicator.

Any tips on this (or even how to maybe profile it myself) would be appreciated.

Of course, this is a highly simplified example.  The real queries are quite massive and span 9-18 tables, databases, etc.

Thanks

**EDIT**

The DB2 is on `iSeries` and I have no idea what version it is.  Everything I try to use gives an error.  I want to say it's version 8 but I really don't know.

If anyone wants to clue me in on how to give more information I will.  I don't know much about DB2.

Comment: You may want to start by mentioning your DB2 version and platform. However, there is no generic answer to this question: you cannot tune massive queries spanning 9-18 tables and databases by looking at a simplified example.

Comment: I know around zero about DB2 but it must not be that difficult to find the version. Try these suggestions: http://onewebsql.com/blog/finding-your-db2-version

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that too.  I think my permissions are too restricted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the explain facilities in DB2 to answer this question, it's highly specific to the actual queries you are executing, and you can't get a general answer.

IBM i 7.2 (and previous versions) have [Visual Explain](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/ssw_ibm_i_72/rzajq/visexpl.htm).

If you are restricted from doing this, then you need to speak to the system or database administrator for your environment.